# Issues with using setTimeout inside of a for loop with arrays

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, settimeout, setinterval

--- UPDATE ---

Here is another attempt... The issue seems to be that the animation only happens to the third item in the for loop array I'm assuming because of the setTimeout delay.  How can I have the animation fire for each item (3) with a delay?

```
// Breadcrumb Animation

(function(){
    var header = document.getElementById("header"),
        header2 = document.getElementById("header-secondary"),
        banner = document.getElementById("banner");
    var bcLink = [header, header2, banner];
    var myTime = '';
    var myItem = '';
    function delay() {
        setTimeout(fadeIn, myTime);
        function fadeIn() {
            if( myItem.style.opacity !== '1' ) {
                console.log(myItem);
                setInterval(function(){
                    myItem.style.opacity = parseFloat(myItem.style.opacity) + 0.1;
                }, 100);
            }
        }
    }
    var i, len=bcLink.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bcLink[i].style.opacity = 0;
        myItem = bcLink[i];
        myTime = myTime = parseInt(myTime + 2000)
        delay();
    }

})();
```

--- END UPDATE ---

The code below works but I was trying to optimize my code by creating a foor loop that will loop through each of the items (my attempt is commented out).  I'm currently using 3 items on my page (header, header2, banner) that will load one after the other, but the second should not start until the first loads, the third should not start until the second item loads, and so on.  This code will eventually be used for breadcrumbs where the amount of items will be uncertain but they will still load one after the other. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    (function(){
        var header = document.getElementById("header"),
            header2 = document.getElementById("header-secondary"),
            banner = document.getElementById("banner");
        var bcLink = [header, header2, banner];
        var myTime = '';
        function fadeIn(name, speed) {
            if( name.style.opacity !== '1' ) {
                setInterval(function(){

                    name.style.opacity = parseFloat(name.style.opacity) + 0.1;
                }, speed);
            }
        }
        function delay(funct, time) {
            setTimeout(function() {funct}, time);
        }
            bcLink[0].style.opacity = 0;
            bcLink[1].style.opacity = 0;
            bcLink[2].style.opacity = 0;
            setTimeout(function(){fadeIn(bcLink[0], 100)}, 0);
            setTimeout(function(){fadeIn(bcLink[1], 100)}, 1000);
            setTimeout(function(){fadeIn(bcLink[2], 100)}, 2000);
//      for(var i = 0; i < bcLink.length; i++) {
//          bcLink[i].style.opacity = 0;
//          delay(fadeIn(bcLink[i],100), i + 000);
//      }
    })();
```

Comment: It seems like the first to bcLink[i] variables are deleted by the time setTimeout actually launches.  What is a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery animation queue, not timeout.

http://blog.bigbinary.com/2010/02/02/understanding-jquery-effects-queue.html

Comment: I really wanted to achieve this using pure javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
delay(fadeIn(bcLink[i],100), i + 000);
```

to:

```
setTimeout(function(){fadeIn(bcLink[i], 100)}, i * 1000);
```